# Standard, positive spam test for Akismet

Tags: spam, spam-prevention, akismet

Is there a standard test-case message for Akismet?

Basically, it should work like the [GTUBE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTUBE) test case for SpamAssasin (which will always get marked as spam), but for Akismet.  I tried the GTUBE string but (to my surprise) Akismet gave green light.

And no, I don't want to use

> buy viagra buy viagra hello I'm nigerian prince

Or anything really spammy like that.  What I'd like to see is a standard test case to give Akismet a very basic sanity check.  Is this a thing?

*(Sorry for the spam ;)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As described in our [API docs](https://akismet.com/development/api/#detailed-docs), to guarantee a `true` response, send the value `viagra-test-123` as the `comment_author` parameter.

To guarantee a `false` response, send the value `administrator` for the `user_role` parameter.

Comment: Oh gosh, I wish you guys could have chosen something less viagraesque ;) But thanks!

Comment: Sadly, phpbb does not allow dashes in registered user names. So use this email instead: ```akismet-guaranteed-spam@example.com```

Answer (score 4):

> To simulate a positive (spam) result, make a comment-check API call with the comment_author set to viagra-test-123 or comment_author_email set to akismet-guaranteed-spam@example.com.

So you can use `akismet-guaranteed-spam@example.com` for the email if you prefer not to use test strings with "viagra" in a professional environment. :)